# My logo text isn't displayed correctly in grid display

Tags: html, css

[image: logo text not showing correctly!]

I'm trying to make the logo take full width instead of leaving a white background around it.

```css
body {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  background-image: url(./hero-bg.jpg);
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 10% auto;
  grid-template-rows: 15% auto auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: "logo header header header" "sidebar section section section" "sidebar main main main " "sidebar footer footer footer";
}

.logo {
  grid-area: logo;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.55);
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">policy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h1 class="logo">Batoot</h1>
  <aside>sidebar</aside>
  <section>section</section>
  <main>main content</main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

I tried changing the grid template area property but it did not solve my problem

Comment: the snipet dosent seem to be working

Comment: This is the case for me as well.

Comment: Culd you give a more complete snippet that positions the other elements? And why have you defined a two column grid and then named 4 columns in the area definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just set the columns and rows where you want stuff and dispense with the areas if I were to do this.

I added some borders and background colors just to illustrate where things are.

```css
body {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #FFFF3344;
  padding-top: 0;
  border: solid green 1px;
}

nav {
  display: none;
}

.page {
  background-color: #0000FF0C;
  border: solid 1px cyan;
  background-image: url(./hero-bg.jpg);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.logo {
  grid-area: logo;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.55);
  border: solid 2px lime;
  /* deal with using h1 not a div by setting margin and padding */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

main {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3;
}

aside {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
  border: solid blue 1px;
}

footer {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">policy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h1 class="logo">Batoot</h1>
  <aside>sidebar</aside>
  <section>section</section>
  <main>main content</main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked really well when I added the margin and padding like you did.